# fortran (std2003)conversion of logical to numeric type

Tags: type-conversion, fortran, gfortran

I have some older program I try to compile. I get an error

```
            if (sum(npsortie>0)) write(*,'(a,i8,a,i8,a,i8,a,i8,a)') &
                  1
Error: 'array' argument of 'sum' intrinsic at (1) must have a numeric type
advect.f90:577:21:


           if(sum(int(mask_part))>0) then
                     1
Error: 'a' argument of 'int' intrinsic at (1) must have a numeric type
advect.f90:580:69:


             meanz=sum(ztra1(1:numpart),DIM=1,MASK=mask_part)/sum(int(mask_part))
                                                                     1
Error: 'a' argument of 'int' intrinsic at (1) must have a numeric type
```

`mask_part` and `npsortie` are arrays of LOGICAL. I use gfortran-7, this is the only compiler version I can use, because of libraries which are compiled with this compiler version.

The parameters to the compiler are

```
gfortran-7 -O2 -fopenmp -pedantic -std=f2003 -cpp -Wall -fconvert=swap -fall-intrinsics -fmax-errors=20 -I /usr/include -L /urs/include -c advect.f90
```

For a hint on how to fix this I would be very grateful. From the documentation I see that it used to work implicitly, but this seems to have changed.

Comment: Please use the formatting for code that is available in the code editor. Also use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions.

Comment: Please follow [mcve] and [ask]. While there are some code lines available quoted in the error messages, you really have to show some more complete piece of code. Preferably something that we can test and get the same result as you. BTW, you typically do *not* want `-pedantic` and doubly not so for old programs.

Comment: Look at the `COUNT()` intrinsic, it is probably what you need instead of the type conversion. We might have a duplicate but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that `npsortie` and `mask_part` are indeed `logical`:

```
if (sum(npsortie>0)) ...`
```

this appears to query, whether there are any .true. elements of the logical array. For that one should use `if (any(npsortie)) ...`.

```
if(sum(int(mask_part))>0) ...
```

this appears to do the same and `if (any(mask_part)) ...` should be equivalent.

```
meanz=sum(ztra1(1:numpart),DIM=1,MASK=mask_part)/sum(int(mask_part))
```

here `sum(int(mask_part))` seems to be the number of .true. elements. For that use `count(mask_part)` instead. the count intrinsic counts the number of true elements in the array.

---

If you had

```
if (sum(numeric_array>0)) ...
```

and you want to know the count of numeric elements that have a value higher than zero, use `count(numeric_array>0)`.